# How to edit Firefox URL autocomplete weights

Tags: firefox, autocomplete

I'm used to using the URL autocompletion in Firefox to access my favorite websites. It's quicker and more convenient than mucking around with the mouse to access bookmark lists -- just Ctrl-L, a few strategically chosen letters of the URL, down, Enter.

Recently one of my favorites seems to have lost its weight in whatever database Firefox uses to select autocomplete results -- I can still get it to show in the autocomplete dropdown, but it takes significantly more characters typed than it used to do.

Is there any way to artificially increase Firefox's perception of how popular that URL is with me -- except for typing it in by hand hundreds of times?

(Firefox 27.0.1, Windows 7)